# Trying to install w10 on an external ssd to use on a mac, can I just clone drive from windows notebook?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, boot-camp, clone

I've tried one tutorial using virtualbox to get it on there and it failed, it would just crash in the middle of using windows, I was going to try another using parallels and win2usb, then I had the idea.

I have aomei backupper which provides bootable system clones, which I make for my windows laptop.

Can I do that, and add bootcamp drivers later from usb and it will preserve my programs, files, etc? what will happen if windows is activated on two machines?

Comment: I know almost nothing about bootcamp, but what little I know, I am 95% sure it doesn't support booting to Windows from an external device.

Comment: It's not that the Mac won't boot from an external [Mac will boot from anything if it's set up correctly], it's that Windows doesn't like to. It also won't have any correct drivers. It's just not going to be a simple task. You'd probably have to run some kind of sysprep setup to get it to boot at all [not something I'm too familiar with] & if you manage to get it to work, then you could get the BC driver pack installed.

Comment: Unlike Mac, Windows installs only the drivers for the specific hardware it's installed on. Mac installs all drivers for all Macs capable of booting from that OS, which is why it's so easy to move a Mac boot drive to another Mac & it just works.

Comment: I'll give it a try, if it's not bootable, then I'll do the parallels tutorial, or there's another one with vmware, but yeah it doesn't seem that easy to get w10 on an external but there are some recent guides that show it is possible.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - does that still apply if you remove the drive & drop it straight into another PC? Or better still, try to boot it as an external drive on another PC? I've not done it in a while but it used to be a sure-fire way to **not** boot a new machine. Macs have been able to do this without issue since the 90s.

Comment: Anyway - only answer is "Try it & see if it works". It probably won't… because Windows doesn't like booting from external drives.

Comment: I tried, it worked, perfect clone, it started installing bootcamp drivers, then it crashed, but it did that same type of crash before, I suspect it doesn't like my ssd and cheap enclosure I house it in, I'm going to try with a traditional hdd, if it still crashes then I'll know my macbook hates external windows.

Comment: same violent crash on a much slower experience hdd, once it crashes it doesn't even try to load back into windows again through efi boot, so either something with my macbook being too old (2012) or the fact I have a 3rd party ssd in it, I do think cloning is a good method for other macs though as it was perfect copy, anyway, not doing bootcamp internal the way it crashes no way. Maybe a crippled 2gb vm is as far as I go with w10 on this mac.